# UIPOPOVER for Iphone? or is it fake?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Can anyone take a look a this ? : http://www.woowoomac.com/storage/awesome-note-iphone-note-todo-app-menus.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1268581762429

As we know iphone 4.0 does not support UIPopovers - any idea how did they manage to create a pop over like that ?

Answer (score 13):

I created a class myself with the exact same interface as the UIPopoverController, but generalized for the iPhone. It allows you to customize the background and arrow for the popover as well. 
The tricky part is calculating the correct rectangle for the arrow image and resizing the background image properly, but other than that it's just standard UIView stuff (adding subviews, etc).

You can find a sample project including the core popover classes here: https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Comment: Werner - I've been looking for such class on gitub but there is nothing like that.

Comment: This is great.  I am so excited to use it.  The only problem I am having is the present in rect is showing the popover at the top of the view.  How can I move the popover to the button it is being shown from.  Also, is there anyway i can set a border around the popover.  Thanks again.  This is great work

Comment: A border can be created by using a custom background image. You have to set the correct margins for this new background image in the properties for it to work correctly. Presenting a popover from a button can be done simply by using presentPopoverFromRect:button.bounds inView:button

Answer (score 3):

Sublcass a UIView and display your content inside it. This way you can fake a pop over on the iPhone.