# Cannot assign values in iphone version of program

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am attempting to make my iPad app universal. However I am havinng a little issue. I have this code. In my masterviewcontroller and depending on what country is selected, said country is passed to my detailviewcontroller and my country is loaded in my detailview.

My problem is that, when this code is run on my iphone, my activecountry is null. but when it is run on the ipad it has a value. I have selected the correct class for the iPhone version and Im not exactly sure why as i do have a detailviewcontroller view in my iphone storyboard.

My question therefore is, what is stopping me from passing my value into self.detailviewcontroller.activecountry.

Would love any help I could get with this issue.

Thanks

PS. the ipad detailview controller on the ipad version is the detailversion of uisplitview controller.

```
   if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {

    lat =  15.4166152;
    lon =-61.353149;

    [self.detailViewController animateToPosition:MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(lon,lat) time:1.0 height:0.1];


    ThridViewController *thrid=[[ThridViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:thrid animated:YES];

       [thrid setTitle:@"America"];
     self.detailViewController.activeCountry=@"America";
    NSLog(@"The active country is  %@",self.detailViewController.activeCountry);
    }
    else
    {

        lat =  15.4166152;
        lon =-61.353149;

        [self.detailViewController animateToPosition:MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(lon,lat) time:1.0 height:0.1];


        ThridViewController *thrid=[[ThridViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:thrid animated:YES];

        [thrid setTitle:@"America"];
        self.detailViewController.activeCountry=@"America";
        NSLog(@"The active country is  %@",self.detailViewController.activeCountry);
    }
```

}

**Update**
I think I notice something wrong.

In my app delegate, in the code that says that my iPad is running I call init on the detailview controller but in the iPhone i do no such thing. Mainly cause Im not sure how. because my detailviewcontroller doesnt start off being seen.

**Update-App Delegate**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


   [DBAccess copyDatabaseIfNeeded];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        //Place iPhone code
    } else {

        // Place iPad-specific code here...

    MasterViewController *left=[[MasterViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navigLeft=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:left];

    DetailViewController *detail=[[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navigRight=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detail];

    left.detailViewController = detail;

    UISplitViewController *splitViewController=[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
    splitViewController.delegate=detail;

    splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigLeft,navigRight,nil];

           }
return YES;

 }
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the iPad code from your app delegate and we'll see what we need to do for the iPhone.

Comment: @Fluffhead Hi, I added the app delegate code. I am not exactly sure of when to initialize my detailviewcontroller. I was thinking of having it on my main view and doing something like a uipopover ( does apple allow uipopover in iPhone apps btw? or just ipad. I saw a youtube video of some guy doing it and everyone was telling him his app would be rejected)

Comment: Sammie, you can either use a UIView to "fake" the popover, or try a custom class like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987218/uipopover-for-iphone-or-is-it-fake.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first question would be: Why are you duplicating so much code for iPhone and iPad? In general, you only need to put what is DIFFERENT in those conditional statements - so very often that is just the UI specific code. I would put just the device specific in those conditionals and leave the commonly used code outside, for all devices to use. That may fix your problem right there.

If that doesn't solve the issue, insert a breakpoint at:

```
 self.detailViewController.activeCountry=@"America";
```

and print the value for: self.detailViewController
as well as self.detailViewController.activeCountry and let us know what they say.

Comment: Im aware of the need of not duplicating code, this block of code does not even need to specify what device is being used but that was part of troubleshooting. As advised I added the break point. on the iPhone i get _detailViewController DetailViewController * nil 0x00000000 and self.detailViewController.activeCountry is null from my nslog

Comment: Well, there is a big clue: your _detailViewController is nil, so you can't assign a value to its activeCountry property. Looks like you need to check where you are alloc/init'ing it.